# ObservableCollection as DependenceProperty and binding problems

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, dependency-properties

I've created a Chart control and after a while I decided to add multiserie capabilities to it. I implemented the feature using a dependence property of type `ObservableCollection<ChartSerie>` like this:

```
private static DependencyPropertyKey SeriesPropertyKey = DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly("Series", typeof(ObservableCollection<ChartSerie>), typeof(Chart), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<ChartSerie>()));
public static DependencyProperty SeriesProperty = SeriesPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;
```

I use this property from XAML calling it this way:

```
    <chart:Chart>
        <chart:Chart.Series>
            <chart:ChartSerie Data="{Binding ChartData1}"/>
            <chart:ChartSerie Data="{Binding ChartData2}" />
        </chart:Chart.Series>
    </chart:Chart>
```

The ChartSerie code is just a container of the ChartData:

```
public static DependencyProperty DataProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(ObservableCollection<ChartPoint>), typeof(ChartSerie), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnDataChanged));
```

The problem I'm facing is that the ChartSerie instances are not being populated with the data coming from the binding. Their Data property is always set to null. I have no binding errors at the output of the visual studio.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: After digging a bit looks like there is a real binding issue here. Looks like the DataContext of Chart is not inherited by ChartSerie. ChartSerie is a FrameworkElement just in case this matters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I recall, you need to define your own non-generic collection rather than exposing a generic `ObservableCollection<Whatever>`:

```
public class ChartSeriesCollection : ObservableCollection<ChartSeries>
{
}

...

public static readonly DependencyProperty ChartSeriesProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "ChartSeries",
    typeof(ChartSeriesCollection),
    typeof(MyClass));
```

If you don't do this, things get very weird indeed.

Comment: Mmmm ... do you have any hint about why is this need? Anyway I will check. Initially I was exposing the generic collection  as a single  dependence property of the chart (the data of just a serie,not as a list of series) and it was working.

Comment: I replaced the collection and now I'm seeing binding issues, can you check my edit? Thanks!

Comment: You should point me to your blog article in this first question :) Thanks again Kent.